# ControlStoryboardAction in the View that triggered by event in the ViewModel

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, eventtrigger

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="DownloadStartedEvent">
       <ei:ControlStoryboardAction/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

DownloadStartedEvent is some public event on my ViewModel.  I want this trigger on my View to start a StoryBoard when the DownloadStartedEvent on the ViewModel is fired. Is there a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

It should work when you bind the EventName to the event of the DataContext (aka. your viewmodel)

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="{Binding DownloadStartedEvent}">
   <ei:ControlStoryboardAction/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks you are right ! but now I have another problem. I want to use <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="" MethodName="" /> inside the trigger, but I want TaretObject to be some instance that is sitting in the view, How can do that ?

Comment: Wait, about my first question, it seems that it dosen't work. the EventName parameter dose not seem to have any affect. I can remove it, and the trigger is triggered any way.